# How to select a specific row in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im using  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and i wanted to dump something from the database.
Its holding over 585k users.
I wanted to ask how i can select a specific row in a column
Like the column is named "User_ResetKey" in the database US_HBS_MEMBERS the table would be US_UserInfo, im really a noob in that maybe someone can help me the row number would be 123921

I mean how i can fetch data what is in the row number 123921?

regards,
jamsb

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` (along with a `SELECT`, of course).

Comment: Can you give me maybe the full query? Im really noob in that..

Comment: You really need to invest in or find a good SQL introduction book. This question is premature. If someone's let you loose on a server with production data I'm really concerned.

Comment: I wnat only a answer on my question not more, i want only HELP.

Comment: **Get a reference book and learn the basics**. This is not an optional step. You can do enormous amounts of damage if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I want still the answer of my question what are you doing if you cant answer my question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for tutorials or introductions. [Hire a professional](http://codementor.io) to coach you if it's necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because zero effort from op. Sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via using

```
Row_number()
```

here you are ,

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User_ResetKey] ) AS rownumber,
*
FROM [US_HBS_MEMBERS].[dbo].[US_UserInfo]
) AS myTable
WHERE rownumber = 123921
```

supposed your schema is 'dbo'.

Comment: THANKS I LOVE YOU!!!!

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible!!

Comment: in the same second that I posted this answer, i get voted by -1 , could I ask why ??

Comment: I dont know i didnt press anything i would give you +1

Comment: thanks bro, waiting ur feedback ..

Comment: ahmed I didn't DV you, but I assure you the question gets deleted. So it is effort for nothing on your part. Sorry.

Comment: Drow, I think this question is valid one, he asking about row_number, I belave it is not basic one for deleting it, 
thanks at all.

Comment: Fair enough. You may be right. Please do an edit on the question to clean up the wording.

Comment: I tried it and i got "1" as output..

Comment: i want only the data of the rownumber 123921 in the column "User_ResetKey" in the Table US_UserInfo and from the database US_HBS_MEMBERS

Comment: Jamsb, are u sure you selected the code correctly , I tested it before posting, and it is working fine,

Comment: SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User_ResetKey]) AS rownumber,
  *
FROM [US_HBS_MEMBERS].[dbo].[US_UserInfo]) AS myTable
WHERE rownumber = 123921 
what i should use by mytable? like i said  
i want only the data of the rownumber 123921 in the column "User_ResetKey" in the Table US_UserInfo and from the database US_HBS_MEMBERS

Comment: myTable is just alias , use it as it is, for more details <http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp>

Comment: how i can fetch now the data?